# Web based workflow designer that can be used with ASP.Net application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have been diving heavily into Workflow Foundation 4 and slowly realized we cannot host the designer in ASP.Net. What’s more, the designer is not suited to a non-developer. 
We are looking for a web based solution we can tie into an ASP.Net application. Workflows will not be incredibly complicated.

As an example, say we have a Request for Information (RFI) document that is created in our system. The flow for that RFI is as follows:  When the RFI is created UserA and UserB need to be notified. UserA is responsible for approving the RFI.  UserA needs to respond within in 3 days. UserA will be notified after the 3rd day. If after 6 days close the RFI and notify UserA and UserB.

Workflows will only serve as the communication flow between users and nothing more.  So, the designer will allow users to define who gets notified when and no expressions will need to be compiled (like in WF4 for more complicated flows). All we need is something where a user drags predefined boxes onto a workspace and can draw lines from one box to another and pick from a list of users and timeframes.

Comment: And your solution was?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign, please see my edits to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very long hunt for something, I did not find what I was looking for. We decided to come up with our own solution.

We used a combination of [jsPLumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/statemachine/dom.html) and [Stateless](https://github.com/nblumhardt/stateless)